# Finding the $n$th moment of a gaussian distributed random variable $X$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, power-series, exponential-function, expected-value

Suppose that $X \sim N(0, 1)$ is a Gaussian random variable with a density $f_X(x) = \frac{\exp(-(1/2)x^2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Suppose that it is know that $\mathbb{E}(\exp(tX)) = \exp(t^2/2)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{E}(\exp(tX)) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n)$. Given this information I have to deduce that $\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \begin{cases}\prod_{j=1}^{n/2}(2j - 1)&: n \equiv 0 (\mod 2)\\ 0 &: n \equiv 1 (\mod 2)\end{cases}$. Well, with the given information we know that $\exp(t^2/2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n) \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2n}}{2^n(n!)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n)$, but I'm not sure how to proceed onwards from this, as to my understanding, the only thing we know is that the sequences of parties sums of both of the series are equal.

Comment: The Taylor series of $e^x$ is unique, so in fact the two series can be equated term by term. To find $\mathbb{E}X^n$ All you have to do is differentiate $e^{t^2/2}$ $n$ times and evaluate at $x=0$.

Comment: You can write the last as $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2m}}{2^m(m!)} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n)$ and then match coefficients (using @Enforce's comment).  When $n$ is odd you get $0 = \frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n)$ while when $n$ is even and $m=\frac n2$ you get $\frac{1}{2^{n/2}\left(\frac n2!\right)} = \frac{1}{n!}\mathbb{E}(X^n)$ which you can rearrange to get the result

Comment: @Henry I see! Currently I'm getting bogged down in the simplification process: $\mathbb{E}(X^n) = \frac{n!}{2^{(n/2)(n/2)!}} = \frac{\prod_{j = n/2 + 1}^nj}{2^{n/2}} = \frac{\prod_{j = k + 1}^{2k}j}{2^k}$ which then splits into yet more cases depending on the parity of $k$. I have a feeling that there must a simpler way to rearrange the terms.

For the case of an odd $n$, is the reason why $\mathbb{E}(X^n) = 0$ because there is no $m$ for which $2m = n$?

Comment: That last point was what I used.  Alternatively, $X$ is symmetric about $0$ and so too is $X^n$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: On simplifying the factorials when $n$ is even, you have $\frac{1\times 2\times 3 \times 4 \times \cdots \times (n-1)\times n}{(2\times1)\times (2\times 2)\times \cdots \times (2 \times \frac n2) } = 1 \times 3 \times \cdots \times (n-1)$